# How to add a Many-To-Many object to an existing object in django

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many, django-testing

I have a few simple classes: Visitor, Student and Visit

The Visit model looks like this:

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s : %s" % (self.visitor, self.students)


class Student(models.Model):
    visitors = models.ManyToManyField(Visitor, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.last_name, self.first_name)


class Visitor(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'Parent'),
        ('O', 'Other Parent'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, validators=[alphaonly])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, validators=[alphaonly])
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

For testing purposes - I'm trying to test the creation of a `Visit`

```
class VisitModelTest(TestCase):
"""Test class for the Visit model"""

def create_visit(self):
    visitor = Visitor.objects.create(type='P', first_name='Test', last_name='McTest', birth_date=date(1981, 10, 16))
    student = visitor.student_set.create(first_name='Tester', last_name='McJrTest')
    visit = visitor.visit_set.create(visitor=visitor)
    visit.students.add(student)
    return visit

def test_visit_creation(self):
    visit = self.create_visit()
    self.visitor = mixer.blend(Visitor, type='P', first_name='Test', last_name='McTest', birth_date=date(1981, 10, 16))
    self.students = self.visitor.student_set.create(first_name='Tester', last_name='McJrTest')
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(visit, Visit))
    self.assertEqual(visit.__str__(), "%s : %s" % (self.visitor, self.students))
```

In my line where I call `visit.students.add(student)` nothing is happening.

My assertions fail with this error:

```
self.assertEqual(visit.__str__(), "%s : %s" % (self.visitor, self.students))
AssertionError: 'McTest, Test : visitor_check_in.Student.None' != 
'McTest, Test : McJrTest, Tester'
- McTest, Test : visitor_check_in.Student.None
+ McTest, Test : McJrTest, Tester
```

What is the appropriate way to add a student to that Visit instance?

Comment: simply put visit.student.add(student) ....without 's'

Comment: If I do that - I get the error `Attribute Error: 'Visit' has no attribute 'student'`, because if you look at the model - the attribute is `students` (with the 's').

Answer (score 0):

Create your Student and Visit object first and add it to Visitor later:

```
student = Student.objects.create(first_name='Tester', last_name='McJrTester')
visit = Visit.objects.create(visitor=visitor)
```

and add student

```
visit.students.add(student)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Even when I did that, it still is showing up with `AssertionError: 'McTest, Test : visitor_check_in.Student.None' != 
'McTest, Test : McJrTest, Tester'`